# read csv file with new line character as data java

Tags: java, csv, filereader

I need your help here . Trying to figure out if there is a better solution than manipulation of data in the text file.

So i have a csv file where some of the data has new line characters in it. This file is generated from the salesforce portal

The issue occurs when i try to read this file line by line to insert in a sql table in the database.

```
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    line = bReader.readLine()
```

interprets the new line in the data as end of line . as a result this line is interepreted as 2 lines.
Any idea how can handle such data while reading the file.

Any insights would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried trimming `line` and checking if it is empty? if so - `continue;`

Comment: The question to solve it is: how do you know the newline character is part of the data instead of a real newline in your CSV. if you know the answer to that you could design a solution, otherwise you can't

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already know the answer for moffeltje's question in terms of how to decide which is really valid newline and which one is embeded. If that is the case then, you may use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

One of the features it has "Handling quoted entries with embedded carriage returns (ie entries that span multiple lines)." This may help you working around the issue.

Comment: Agreed. If you ask me, the best answer is, not to try to solve that problem yourself, as it already has been solved many times. Use one of the many available CSV libraries and don't think to much about how it works unless you really need it.

Comment: yeah I read about opsencsv . but i thought if it can be done without this lib.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach I can think of is to compare the last character of the line. each value in the .csv is in quotes . therefore, if the last character is not quote then append the next line to this till a quote is identified.